# React/Vite App: 403 Forbidden Errors with AWS CloudFront

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, vite, amazon-cloudfront

I recently encountered an issue when deploying a React/Vite web application using AWS CodePipeline. While the application runs smoothly in my local development environment, I'm facing a series of "403 Forbidden" errors when the application is deployed to the DEV environment. The error messages look like this:

```
GET https://test.com/test.css net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)
GET https://test.com/test.js net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)
GET https://test.com/assets/index-495cfc72.css net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)
GET https://test.com/assets/index-67e333eb.js net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)
GET https://test.com/favicon.png 403 (Forbidden)
GET https://test.com/manifest.json 403 (Forbidden)
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Could you document your architecture.
I infer that you have a CloudFront distribution.
There's chance you are using S3 as origin for your content and your CodePipeline task is pushing your content to S3.
If you didn't refine how CloudFront is handling errors it usually returns 403 when it does not find a resource at the origin.

Answer (score -1):

It's hard to answer precisely without your exact architecture, but the first place I would start would be checking the access permissions on the S3 bucket hosting your files.

1. Go to S3 in the AWS Console
2. Find your assets bucket, and under `Permissions`, disable `Block all public access` if it's enabled
3. Under `Properties`, you can then set `Static website hosting` settings